# Filter Microsoft Graph List Messages API to only received messages

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-exchange

**Goal:** I'd like to be able to filter the "[List Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta)" API to only return emails that are sent to the user rather than any messages that exist anywhere (such as ones sent out by the user).

Right now, if you query this particular API, you get a list of all of the messages in all folders (including Deleted Items and Clutter folders).

I know that I can filter on `isDraft eq false` to remove the drafts - but I don't know if there's any filter to say don't include messages sent by the user.

**What I've Tried:** I've looked over the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta#example) and didn't see anything about filtering like this. I've also taken a look at the [OData Query Params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters) and dug into the [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) param. The problem is I'm not quite sure what I could even filter on. I do see that there is a sender parameter - but given I've connected via OAuth and haven't asked users to provide their email address I'm not sure I have an easy way to filter on that.

Theoretically, I could first do a request to the https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/ endpoint to get the userPrincipalName and then add a filter on `from/emailAddress/address ne '<userPrincipalName>'` when I call the `/me/messages` endpoint - but that's going to double the number of API calls I'd need to make. Is that the only option I have or is there a better way to go about this?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: You could grab the Upn from the JWT auth token to save yourself from needing to do that extra request.

Comment: Thanks for the response @ChrisJohnson! Could you clarify how one might grab the UPN from the auth token? I'm getting the token via a request to `/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`. I get back token_type, scope, expires_in, ext_expires_in, access_token, and refresh_token. I don't see anything about a UPN in that. For reference I'm looking here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-beta#3-get-a-token

Comment: Grab the access token and decode it (its base64 encoded). Or drop it in JWT.io to decode it and take a look at the payload section. I believe you will see the users upn in there. Its not ideal, as you should treat tokens as opaque incase MS changes its design, but if you really want to save that extra call that is a tradeoff you will need to make.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the explanation @ChrisJohnson - that helps a bunch :) - In thinking it over last night, I think I'll just make the call to "/me/" once at the start and then store the UPN for each user for the system and use that whenever I need to in other calls. Cheers ^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no filter parameter that will achieve this directly. If you want to filter away sent messages - you'll need to either decode the base64 encoded JWT access token and extract the `userPrincipalName` or make a call to the `/me` endpoint and retrieve the `userPrincipalName` from that. Once you have that, you can add a filter of `from/emailAddress/address ne '<userPrincipalName>'`.

Please note that if you are filtering on many things and you have an "order by" param that you'll need to include that param in your filter or you'll receive an error about too many filters.